# Laravel - Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [ #0]

Tags: laravel-4, gmail

I'm trying to send an email from Gmail using Laravel from localhost. I'm getting this error: Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [ #0]

I'm using ssl with port 465. I also tried 587 but it didn't work.

I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14176965/swift-transportexception-connection-could-not-be-established-with-host-smtp-gmai) but it didn't work. I found a lot of people suffering from the same problems, but the solutions I found didn't work.

Comment: I think it helps full: [The connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com?](https://devnote.in/the-connection-could-not-be-established-with-host-smtp-gmail-com)

Comment: Enable IMAP from Gmail.

Answer (score 33):

> ***Editor's note***: disabling SSL verification has **security implications.** Without verification of the authenticity of SSL/HTTPS connections, a malicious attacker can impersonate a trusted endpoint (such as GitHub or some other remote Git host), and you'll be vulnerable to a [Man-in-the-Middle Attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).
>
> #### Be sure you fully understand the security issues before using this as a solution.

In Laravel project directory, edit `config/mail.php` and add the following:

```
'stream' => [
        'ssl' => [
            'allow_self_signed' => true,
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
        ],
    ]
```

It worked for me.

Fyi, my SMTP settings are:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=[Full Gmail Address]
MAIL_PASSWORD=[Google App Password obtained after two step verification on Google Account Page]
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

Comment: I didn't need the stream part. What made the difference was the app password after the two step verification, and php artisan config:cache

Comment: this solved my problem

Comment: this is doesnt works anymore in laravel 9

Comment: verify peer option location has been changed, just define `'verify_peer' => false` into `'smtp'` array for Laravel 9.x

Answer (score 20):

This one line change in `.env` file will make it work

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
```

If it also has no effect try to switch between the mail port

```
MAIL_PORT=587
```

Or

```
MAIL_PORT=465
```

> This will work only if you enable "Allow Less secure app access" under google account

Comment: it works but now emails are not delivered from gmail. its delivered from server now.

Comment: Only SMTP mail server send mail from Gmail.

Answer (score 9):

In your .env file you will need to set the email address and password of your email account:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=test@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=testpassword
```

and in mail.php

```
<?php

return [
    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
    'from' => ['address' => 'yourEmail@gmail.com', 'name' => 'Your Title'],
    'encryption' => 'tls',
    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'pretend' => false,
];
```

and clear the config cache with:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: for live server also need username and password?

Answer (score 6):

here's what is working with me

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=<your email>
MAIL_PASSWORD=<your app password>
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

if you are two auth verification with your account , should be generate new app password and use into you env file. this is what working with me.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried changing the encryption to tls? I currently use a Gmail SMTP sever to send emails from my Laravel app. I use TLS and port 587

Comment: Thats work for me! when I use apache in windows, I need to put tls. So maybe it's an ssl configuration problem.

Answer (score 3):

in localhost you can set your MAIL_DRIVER=smtp but on real server like cpanel you must to set MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail and edit your config/mail.php
'default' => env('MAIL_MAILER', 'sendmail'),
but its not good idea because after you send mail on google you get error on gmail like this :

Be careful with this message
Gmail could not verify that it actually came from tenetup.reminderme@gmail.com. Avoid clicking links, downloading attachments, or replying with personal information.

Answer (score 1):

Hi If you Try all Things and Nothing to do then please Enable SMTP Restrictions then again Disable it (in WHM Account) . Its Working for me.

Answer (score -2):

Change mail driver in both .env and mail.php into MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun