# I am having error while trying to send mail in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have been sending mail normally before with my laravel mail setup below and it works perfectly. But now when i run the app and try to send mail it shows this error
"Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://smtp.gmail.com:587 (No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."

i have researched and tried different means to setup my laravel mail, but still i get errors, and my Less secure app access for my gmail is turned on.

My .env

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=delivery@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=delivery@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

mail.php

```
'default' => env('MAIL_MAILER', 'smtp'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Mailer Configurations
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  

'mailers' => [
    'smtp' => [
        'transport' => 'smtp',
        'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
        'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
        'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
        'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
        'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
        'timeout' => null,
        'auth_mode' => null,
    ],

    'ses' => [
        'transport' => 'ses',
    ],

    'mailgun' => [
        'transport' => 'mailgun',
    ],

    'postmark' => [
        'transport' => 'postmark',
    ],

    'sendmail' => [
        'transport' => 'sendmail',
        'path' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    ],

    'log' => [
        'transport' => 'log',
        'channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),
    ],

    'array' => [
        'transport' => 'array',
    ],
],
```

Comment: go here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27721120/laravel-connection-could-not-be-established-with-host-smtp-gmail-com-0   It might have your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
return [
/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Mail Driver
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
  | sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
  | your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
  |
  | Supported: "smtp", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill", "ses",
  |            "sparkpost", "log", "array"
  |
 */
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'mail'),
/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | SMTP Host Address
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
  | applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
  | the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
  |
 */
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | SMTP Host Port
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
  | users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
  | stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
  |
 */
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Global "From" Address
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
  | the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
  | used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
  |
 */
'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'service@codegurru.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Job Portal'),
],
/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | E-Mail Encryption Protocol
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
  | the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
  | transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
  |
 */
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | SMTP Server Username
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
  | set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
  | connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
  |
 */
'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Sendmail System Path
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
  | the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
  | been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
  |
 */
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Markdown Mail Settings
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | If you are using Markdown based email rendering, you may configure your
  | theme and component paths here, allowing you to customize the design
  | of the emails. Or, you may simply stick with the Laravel defaults!
  |
 */
'markdown' => [
    'theme' => 'default',
    'paths' => [
        resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
    ],
],
```

];

- in .env file    MAIL_DRIVER=smtp    MAIL_HOST=mail.domain.com
  MAIL_PORT=465    MAIL_USERNAME=xyz@xyz.com    MAIL_PASSWORD=*********
  MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

Comment: Thank you for your help, after doing what you suggested i got an error which shows  --Expected response code 220 but got an empty response"

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the inbox of the Gmail account you are using as SMTP. Looks like it access may be restricted from Gmail. You may have received the mail related to some app accessing your account. You need to authorize and allow the permissions.

Comment: I have checked my Gmail inbox and I didn't receive any mail related to some app accessing account