# Laravel 5.2: Error sending mail using GMail

Tags: php, email, laravel-5

I'm trying to send an email from localhost with Laravel 5.2 (using PHP 7.0.8 and XAMPP), but I get this error:

```
Swift_TransportException in StreamBuffer.php line 269:
Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [ #0]
```

The values of my loaded mail config looks like this (using Config::get("mail")):

```
  "driver" => "smtp"
  "host" => "smtp.gmail.com"
  "port" => "465"
  "from" => array:2 [
    "address" => "***@gmail.com"
    "name" => "MY_NAME"
  ]
  "encryption" => "ssl"
  "username" => "***@gmail.com"
  "password" => "***"
  "sendmail" => "C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -bs"
```

I've googled the last few days around 10 hours, but did not find a solution which is working. I've also tried to change `"port" => "587"` and `"encryption" => "tls"`, but this did not work either. The error is:

```
ErrorException in StreamBuffer.php line 95:
stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
```

In my Google Account I've already allowed "less secure apps". Is there anything I can try?

btw: with the PHP mail function it is possible to send emails using my gmail account.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift\_TransportException Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14176965/swift-transportexception-connection-could-not-be-established-with-host-smtp-gmai)