# How to achieve password reset functionality in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I implemented laravel 5.4 auth login. My other functionality is in working like login, logout etc. But for password reset functionality I am receiving following error. I am confused where I am wrong.

> Swift_TransportException in StreamBuffer.php line 268: Connection
>   could not be established with host smtp.thenaturalgolfcourse.com
>   [php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not
>   known #0]

Below is my .env file detail is reqired for mail setting.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mysite.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=support@mysite.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

same details I used in mail.php like below

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mysite.com'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 465),
'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'support@mysite.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'The My Site'),
],
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME','support@mysite.com'),
'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD','mypassword'),
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
'pretend' => false,
'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],
];
```

Please give me solution or tell me where I am wrong..

Comment: Try port 587 instead of 465

Comment: make sure SMTP service is enabled for your server...

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14176965/swift-transportexception-connection-could-not-be-established-with-host-smtp-gmai

Comment: Hey Naincy.. I tried port 587 at both file mail.php and .env also but still get same error..

Comment: SMTP is enabled.. I can send other email.. @ hosting site port number is 465 for outgoing.. so I used 465...