# Laravel mail 500

Tags: laravel

Im trying to send mail from my local laravel project but get err0r 500.Can´t get anything on console but POST error 500.

***.ENV***

> MAIL_MAILER=smtp
> MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
> MAIL_PORT=587
> MAIL_USERNAME=vidalmanriquecab@gmail.com
> MAIL_PASSWORD=1234
> MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
> MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=vidalmanriquecab@gmail.com

***ROUTES***

```
use App\Mail\ContactoMailable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
Route::post('correo',function(){
    $data=request()->all();
    $correo= new ContactoMailable;
    Mail::to($data['email'])->send($correo);
    return view('contacto');
})->name('correo');
```

***BLADE CONTACT FORM***

```
@extends('layouts.main-layout')
@section('styles')
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/header.css') }}">
@endsection
@section('content')
    <p>Contacta con nosotros utilizando este formulario para que nos pongamos en contacto contigo. Cuanta más información nos des, más ágiles seremos para ofrecerte una solución a la medida de tus necesidades.

        Si prefieres, puedes contactar con nosotros en horario de 9:00 a 14:00 en el teléfono 983 154 444</p>
    <div id="contacto">
        <form id="contact_form" method="POST" action="{{ route('correo') }}">
            @csrf
            @method('post')
```

***MAILABLE***

```
class ContactoMailable extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $subject="Info de contacto";
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('msg.mensaje');
    }
}
```

Again, any help welcome. Thanks in advance

Comment: did you check for logs in laravel.log

Comment: exception":"[object] (Facade\\Ignition\\Exceptions\\ViewException(code: 0): Undefined variable: name (View: C:\\laragon\\www\\ayudas-ocm\
esources\\views\\msg\\mensaje.blade.php) at C:\\laragon\\www\\ayudas-ocm\
esources\\views/msg/mensaje.blade.php:7)
[stacktrace][previous exception] [object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Undefined variable: name at C:\\laragon\\www\\ayudas-ocm\\storage\\framework\\views\\6af63c215d4f2225356326d6c5ee8ff7b6c3ad16.php:7)
[stacktrace]

Comment: it says undefined variable 'name' but it is

Comment: local.ERROR: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed at C:\\laragon\\www\\ayudas-ocm\\vendor\\swiftmailer\\swiftmailer\\lib\\classes\\Swift\\Transport\\StreamBuffer.php:94)

Comment: I searched for google for term local.ERROR: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): . Its listing few SO articles. Can you please go through those

Comment: Also,please try sending plain text in the blade removing all the variables to cross check

Comment: i came to this. sorry no SO. https://discourse.laminas.dev/t/stream-socket-enable-crypto-ssl-operation-failed-with-code-in-zend-mail/1130 . then another error and came to this, where i´m stuck https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14176965/swift-transportexception-connection-could-not-be-established-with-host-smtp-gmai

Comment: user credintials are correct. tried to flush cache and all that stuff. Also got my antiv down for a try, but nothing else matters...

Comment: I came to this after various trials, and now it´s working to me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693528/expected-response-code-220-but-got-code-with-message-in-laravel. Thanks @mightyteja

Answer (score 2):

To me, solution was in this post

[Expected response code 220 but got code "", with message "" in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693528/expected-response-code-220-but-got-code-with-message-in-laravel)

Basically you have to enable double check security (Gmail) and then generate an app password, which is used in .env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=<<your email address>>
MAIL_PASSWORD=<<app password>>
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```